# Is it possible to create generic class which only accepts a type which has a certain property

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I want to create a class "Indicator" that will accept 'Control' and set its 'Image' property.

Since `Control` doesn't have an Image property, **I want to implement a template class** ("Indicator") **which will only accept classes which have this property** (Image).

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use reflection to check if an object has the property you need, but you will be able to pass any control instance anyway...

Comment: "accept type". I would recommend fixing the title.

Comment: It would be much better to use an interface that defines `Image` and apply that to the classes. Might not be possible if the types are sealed or if the instances are created out of your control. Then you can use `Indicator<T> where T : Control, IImageControl`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We *could* change the way how an instance of this class is created by adding a private parameterless constructor and another public ctor in which we'll do our type checks:

```
class Indicator<T> where T : Control
{
    private T _control;

    private Indicator() 
    {
    }

    public Indicator(T control)
    {
       if(control.GetType().GetProperties().All(p => p.Name != "Image" || p.PropertyType != typeof(Image)))
       { 
          throw new ArgumentException("This type of control is not supported");
       }
       this._control = control;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work for `Control` too, as long as you derive from it and implement the interface (the property is already there, so that is fine). +1 Fabjan

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Indeed, a good solution now it's been edited :)  +1 indeed!

Comment: Don't you want `.Any` instead of `.All`?

Comment: @TrevorPilley Well the idea behind this code is that we'd like to throw exception only if necessary, but to do that we must be sure that there is no property that satisfies condition and to do that we must check them *all*, however it's still possible to use `.Any` and inverse condition, smth like `if(!foo.Any(goodProperty))` but `.All` is exactly what we need, so why not use it ? In this case it's more of matter of taste

Comment: @Fabjan don't you require a property called `Image` of type `Image`? your code is saying if they are _not all called Image or not all of type Image_ throw - maybe it's just me but I'd find it more obvious if you had `if (!control.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p => p.Name == "Image" && p.PropertyType == typeof(Image))`

Comment: @TrevorPilley Well, what i require is to check that if *all* properties are *not* Image (it means that there is no Image property among them) then throw exception. But still it's matter of taste and way of thinking.

Comment: @Fabjan I think the problem I have with it is that you aren't ensuring there is a property called Image which has a type of Image, just that there is a property called Image and a property with the type Image (not necessarily the same property) which could lead to a bug

Comment: @Fabjan This case `class MyClass4 : Control { public string Image { get; set; } public Image Picture {get; set;} }` works and shouldn't - that's what I'm getting at.

Comment: @TrevorPilley Actually it doesn't, have a look at this : http://rextester.com/UVJN87628

Answer (score 4):

You can use reflection to get the property of your object:

```
public class ImagePropertyModifier 
{
    private PropertyInfo GetImageProperty(object obj)
    {
        var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Image");

        if (property == null)
            throw new Exception("Object has no Image property.");

        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            throw new Exception("Object's Image property is not a string.");

        return property;
    }

    private static string GetImage(object obj)
    {           
        return GetImageProperty(obj).GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
    }        

    private static string SetImage(object obj, string value)
    {
        GetImageProperty(obj).SetValue(obj, value);
    }        
}
```

Note that this code assumes that `Image` is a string (path to an image). You can change the type in accordance with your requirements. It is just an example.

Comment: Wow... this helps me a lot. btw, can we use this with variables which aren't properties?

Comment: Yes, you can use `GetField` and `FieldInfo` too.

Comment: Nice and tidy, +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Fabjan's answer, instead of using reflection to perform the type inspection required to identify the `Image` property every time you instantiate *instances* of the object, you can leverage static constructors to perform that check only when the *type* itself is instantiated:

```
class Indicator<T> where T : Control
{
    static Indicator()
    {
        {
            if (typeof(T).GetProperties().All(p => p.Name != "Image" || p.PropertyType != typeof(Image)))
                throw new Exception(typeof(T).Name + " is not a supported generic type argument because it does not have an Image property");
        }
    }

    private readonly T _control;
    public Indicator(T control)
    {
        _control = control;
    } 
}
```